# Создание объектов для css-класса

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста лаконично инициализировать скрипт для элементов класса `rainbow_text`.

Как видно, сейчас у меня для 3 элементов ручками прописана инициализация. Это не рационально так как их может быть намного больше.

Было бы отлично не использовать циклы

html:

```
<span>header</span>
<br />
<div class="logo">
    weterteyrtutyu<span class="rainbow_text" >sergey kalinin 123</span>wqeqweqwqrvdg
</div>
<br />

<span class="rainbow_text" >qwerty asdf zxzx</span>

<br />

<span>footer</span>

<br />

<span class="rainbow_text" >qzx</span>
```

js:

```
    new KalininRainbowText({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName ('rainbow_text')[0], 
    colorArray: new Array('red', 'lime', 'blue', 'navy', 'green', 'magenta', '#883f46', '#4bb1ff')          
}); 

new KalininRainbowText({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName ('rainbow_text')[1], 
    colorArray: new Array('red', 'lime', 'blue', 'navy', 'green', 'magenta', '#883f46', '#4bb1ff')          
}); 

new KalininRainbowText({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName ('rainbow_text')[2], 
    colorArray: new Array('red', 'lime', 'blue', 'navy', 'green', 'magenta', '#883f46', '#4bb1ff')          
});
```

Comment: было бы логично показать fiddle, как я понимаю KalininRainbowText это ваш собственный объект, и почему он не работает просто с NodeList  - вопрос исключительно ваш.

Comment: да, извиняюсь. вот фиддл
http://jsfiddle.net/yrUJy/

>> почему он не работает просто с NodeList
хотел бы для тренировки попробовать именно такой способ

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('rainbow_text');
var colorArray = ['red', 'lime', 'blue', 'navy', 'green', 'magenta', '#883f46', '#4bb1ff'];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  new KalininRainbowText({element: elements[i], colorArray: colorArray});
}
```